# Mobile Responsiveness Almost Working - Text Issue

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

The mobile responsiveness is almost working all the way for my portfolio website. The main problem I have right now is the main title in the banner section is wrapping around the screen on itself, instead of shrinking (or better, content fit the text (justify or center, while scaling down the font with a good "em" amount) and stack the text vertically, word over word. IDK how to do this.).

The header links collapse nicely into a little sandwich icon and all of the mobile layout changes and effects convert nicely to the mobile size. I tried searching for solutions to fix the banner text and modified the code, but nothing worked. I tried ChatGPT also, and those solutions all failed miserably. (The other problem I have I will post separately.)

This is from the main.js

````
    var $window = $(window),
        $body = $('body');

    // Breakpoints.
        breakpoints({
            xlarge:   [ '1281px',  '1680px' ],
            large:    [ '981px',   '1280px' ],
            medium:   [ '737px',   '980px'  ],
            small:    [ '481px',   '736px'  ],
            xsmall:   [ null,      '480px'  ]
        });

    // Play initial animations on page load.
        $window.on('load', function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $body.removeClass('is-preload');
            }, 100);
        });

    // Touch mode.
        if (browser.mobile)
            $body.addClass('is-touch');

    // Scrolly links.
        $('.scrolly').scrolly({
            speed: 2000
        });

    // Dropdowns.
        $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
            alignment: 'right',
            hideDelay: 350
        });

    // Nav.

        // Title Bar.
            $(
                '<div id="titleBar">' +
                    '<a href="#navPanel" class="toggle"></a>' +
                    '<span class="title">' + $('#logo').html() + '</span>' +
                '</div>'
            )
                .appendTo($body);

        // Panel.
            $(
                '<div id="navPanel">' +
                    '<nav>' +
                        $('#nav').navList() +
                    '</nav>' +
                '</div>'
            )
                .appendTo($body)
                .panel({
                    delay: 500,
                    hideOnClick: true,
                    hideOnSwipe: true,
                    resetScroll: true,
                    resetForms: true,
                    side: 'left',
                    target: $body,
                    visibleClass: 'navPanel-visible'
                });

    // Parallax.
    // Disabled on IE (choppy scrolling) and mobile platforms (poor performance).
        if (browser.name == 'ie'
        ||  browser.mobile) {

            $.fn._parallax = function() {

                return $(this);

            };

        }
        else {

            $.fn._parallax = function() {

                $(this).each(function() {

                    var $this = $(this),
                        on, off;

                    on = function() {

                        $this
                            .css('background-position', 'center 0px');

                        $window
                            .on('scroll._parallax', function() {

                                var pos = parseInt($window.scrollTop()) - parseInt($this.position().top);

                                $this.css('background-position', 'center ' + (pos * -0.15) + 'px');

                            });

                    };

                    off = function() {

                        $this
                            .css('background-position', '');

                        $window
                            .off('scroll._parallax');

                    };

                    breakpoints.on('<=medium', off);
                    breakpoints.on('>medium', on);

                });

                return $(this);

            };

            $window
                .on('load resize', function() {
                    $window.trigger('scroll');
                });

        }```
````